# Is there a matrix $C$ that can make $AB$ return the same result as $BA$ where $C$ is based on $B$?

Tags: matrices

I am given an arbitrary matrix $A$ that I will be multiplying by a rotational matrix $B$ ( both $4\times4$ )

Is there any matrix $C$, based only on manipulation of matrix $B$, that when doing $A(BC)$ will produce the same result as $BA$?

> $BA = A(BC)$

I am trying to find some sort of abstract solution for making matrix multiplication commutative

If it can not only be based on matrix $B$, is there any way to find that matrix $C$ if using matrix $A$ as well?

---

To clarify, let's define a matrix $D = BC$ . Is there a method to obtain a matrix $C$ such that $BA = AD$

Comment: I am not sure the statement: (1)For all $A,B$, there is a $C=C(A,B)$ such that $BA=ABC$. (2) For all $A,B$, there is a $C=C(B)$ such that $BA=ABC$. I consider the statement is the former.

Comment: The ideal solution would be for statement 2, as I believe it could then be applied to statement 1

Comment: If $C$ denpends only on $B$, then the answer depends on $A$. In my view,  $C$ should be a function of both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: That makes sense, then yes. Statement 1 is correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by considering $BA = ABC$ now by multiplying by $B^{-1}A^{-1}$ on the left we get $B^{-1}A^{-1}BA = C$. Now this is only satisfactory when we are working with invertible matrices... If you want something stronger than that I don't think it's possible for a general case.

Comment: They are invertible yes. My concern with this answer is the order of matrix multiplication. In ABC, BC must be multiplied first. So A(BC) is the correct form. With that in mind, wouldn't the removal factor be the inverse of (BC)? Does that affect the outcome?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but note that A(BC) = (AB)C and thus you can just proceed as I wrote. https://people.math.carleton.ca/~kcheung/math/notes/MATH1107/wk05/05_associativity_of_matrix_multiplication.html#:~:text=Matrix%20multiplication%20is%20associative&text=If%20A%20is%20an%20m,%3D(AB)C.

Answer (score 2):

To signify that $C$ only depends on $B,$ let $C=f(B).$ This gives us $BA=ABf(B)$ for all $A.$ Plugging in $A=I,$ we get $f(B)=I.$ Thus, $BA=AB,$ which means $B$ commutes with every matrix. This is only possible if $B$ is a multiple of the identity, and in this case $C=I$ indeed works.

Comment: This seems to imply in practice that the only way it's possible is if you are dealing with identity matrixes. Is that the case?

Comment: You statement is that for all $B$ there is $C=C(B)$ such that for all $A$, $BA=ABC$.